# jq search with args returns null, works fine with hard coded string

Tags: bash, macos, jq

I have a line to get the variable from a json using jq which works fine when I use a string that's hard coded but when I pass in an `--arg` then it returns null

The working code which outputs the value at the specified key

```
jq '.regions."us-west-2"' ids.json
```

The code that's outputting `null`

```
jq --arg region "us-east-1" '.regions."$region"' ids.json
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is searching for the string `$region`, not the result of expanding the variable.

Comment: If you want a variable to be expanded _inside a string_, the syntax is `"\($region)"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the index notation instead of the dot notation:

```sh
jq --arg region "us-east-1" '.regions[$region]' ids.json
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, but I'm curious why that would even make a difference? Does it have to do with the way variables are resolved with dot vs index notation?

Comment: This explains it better than I can: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score -1):

I found a workaround, I don't like it but it does the job:

```
region=us-west-2
jq ".regions.\"$region\"' ids.json
```

Comment: That approach risks code injection issues. Consider `regions='\(...jq code that hangs indefinitely...)'` and you've got a denial-of-service. (There's been discussion of adding support for file I/O to a future version of jq, which could increase the stakes for security impact of injection attacks further).

Comment: Wrong quoting. You must use single-quotes for the jq program to prevent the shell from expanding variable names: `jq --arg region 'us-east-1' '.regions[$region]' ids.json`

Comment: @LéaGris, ...well, that's intentionally what they're doing here -- injecting the variable into the code as a workaround for the approach in the question not working. It's a bad idea, but it doesn't strike me as an unintentional mistake.

Comment: Apart from code injection, there is a more mundane problem with simple shell-based string interpolation: it won't work if the string contains "special" characters, such as literal tabs, newlines, Control-A, ....